# Changing a variable value every 5 seconds and return

Tags: javascript, variables, setinterval

Why this script does not work correctly (freezes sometimes)?

```
var period = 600;

function Boom(){  
    var timeBoom = window.setInterval(function() {  
        if (period > 300) {  
            period = 300;  
            setTimeout(function () {  
                period = 600;  
            }, 1000);  
        } else {  
            period = 600;  
        }  
    }, 5000);       
}

function Shake() {  
    this.draw = function() {   
        setTimeout(function () {  
            Boom()  
        }, 5000)    
    };  
}
```

I need to just every 5 seconds the function `Boom()` was called, but the variable should be changed back again after executing (var period = 600).

Comment: You're creating timeouts inside intervals?

Comment: sooo, you are calling a delayed function and make execute every 5 seconds but make her change variables after 1 second each time its being executed? what exactly are you trying to do man...

Comment: I need a loop in which the function Boom() is called every 5 seconds and changing variable (var period = 300 / 600).

Comment: i see. i have corrected your code, see my answer :)

Comment: Thnx. But then always be the same value (period = 300). The variable should be changed back again after executing Boom() (var period = 600).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok mate, basically you need to get rid of all the un needed timing stuff.

first of all, a brief explanation:

`setTimeout (func, x)` will execute function func **after** x milliseconds.

`setInterval (func, x)` will execute function func **Each** x milliseconds.

so you only need to set interval one time, and let it work. i have corrected your code:

```
var period = 600;

function Boom() {

    if (period != 300) {
        period = 300;
    } else {
        period = 600;
    }

}

function Shake() {
    this.draw = function () {
        var time = new Date().getTime();
        var shakeX = (Math.sin(time * 2.0 * Math.PI / period) + 0);
        this.x = shakeX;
        var shakeY = (Math.sin(time * 2.0 * Math.PI / period) + 0);
        this.y = shakeY;
        this.context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
        this.context.translate(this.x, this.y);
        setInterval(Boom, 5000)
    };
}
```

Comment: And the initial setInterval can just reference Boom without wrapping it in another needless function.

Comment: oh right, i didnt even notice it was wrapped. i corrected the answer, thanks :)

Comment: I think you meant `setInterval(Boom, 5000)`

Comment: Thnx. But then always be the same value (period = 300). The variable should be changed back again after executing (var period = 600).

Comment: it will alternate between 300 and 600 every 5 seconds. if this is not what you wanted, can you please be more specific ?

Answer (score 0):

John Resig -- creator of jQuery -- has a very nice piece on [javascript timers](http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/).

Basically, becuse javascript is single-threaded, `setInterval` is not guaranteed to fire on every interval -- it will miss a beat if the js engine is busy at a particular cycle.

`setTimeout` will always call, but there could be an extra delay if another piece of code is queued up already when the time expires -- that is, the wait is potentially longer than the number of milliseconds you passed in as the second argument.

I'm guessing some of your `setTimeout` code might be getting in the way of one of the  `setInterval` loops, but that's just a guess.

If that's the issue, try naming the anonymous fn you passed into `setInterval`, and then pass it into `setTimeout` instead, with 5000 ms wait, and another call (recursive) to the same function at when the interval expires.